# Is it correct to write 'I just can't give myself an appetite!'?

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to write a line showing the expression that one is unable to get himself/herself to enjoy food and 'I just can't give myself an appetite!' is all that I could think of so I'm wondering if the sentence is grammatically correct and if not, could you kindly give me an example of what I'm looking for?

Comment: 'I just can't seem to get my appetite back.'

Comment: It's valid syntax, and the meaning is reasonably clear.

Comment: @HotLicks Both true, but it's not very idiomatic and sounds weird to me.